# Hiding a Panel Grid row with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

Since I'm not able to define a known count variable for a row id inside a `<h:panelGrid>` table, is there any way to hide a `<tr>` via javascript?

I need to do something like `document.getElementById("rowId")` on a `onclick` button attribute, but there's one button for each row. And each button has to know its row id.

Answer (score 0):

ofCourse if you want to hide a tr just

html:

`<button onclick="hideRow(this)">`

js:

`function hideRow(element){
element.parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none';}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowClasses like this :

```
<h:panelGrid rowClasses="row1 row2 row3 row4...">
    <h:outputText value="row1" />
    <h:outputText value="row2" />
    <h:outputText value="row3" />
    <h:outputText value="row4" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

It will render like this :

```
<table>
    <tr class="row1"><td>row1</td></tr>
    <tr class="row2"><td>row2</td></tr>
    <tr class="row3"><td>row3</td></tr>
    <tr class="row4"><td>row4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now you will be able to access them easily with jQuery for example `$("table tr.row1").hide();` and do whatever you want.

**OR**

You can also access by nth like this : `$("table tr:nth-child(4)").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<button class="button-class">
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button-class').each(function(){
$(this).closest('tr').hide();
});
});
```